# How to open table for specific tr?

Tags: angular

```
<table class="custom-table">
    <tr [ngClass]="{bold:showNewTable}" dnd-draggable [dragData]="sa" (onDragStart)="dnd.set(true);"
        (onDragEnd)="dnd.set(false)" *ngFor="let sa of customerGeneralInfo?.serviceAccount"
        (click)="addToHistory('CA');sa?.accountclassCode=='SAGG' ? getSAGG(sa.p_SA_ID):getServiceAccount(sa.p_SA_ID,'CA');">
        <td>{{sa?.p_SA_ID}}</td>
        <td>{{sa?.address}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="sa?.accountclassCode=='SAGG'">{{sa?.accountclassCode}}</td>
        <td class="full-width">
            <table *ngIf="saggInfo?.serviceAccount?.length > 0 && showNewTable ">
                <tr dnd-draggable [dragData]="saggsa" (onDragStart)="dnd.set(true);" (onDragEnd)="dnd.set(false)"
                    *ngFor="let saggsa of saggInfo?.serviceAccount"
                    (click)="getServiceAccount(saggsa.p_SA_ID);addToHistory('CA');">
                    <td>
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right "></i>
                        {{saggsa?.p_SA_ID}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{saggsa?.address}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have this table and my problem is when i click on tr from first table it opens all my tr and display same data for all tr. Any suggestion how can i open table for only tr that i clicked?

Comment: Can you provide your component code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a property (say `opendId`) in the class with a default value of -1. It will keep the id of the opened `<tr>`. Each time there is a click on a `<tr>`, assign to opendId the index of that tr (taken from ngFor for example). Also, put a condition on the table, if it's parent `<tr>` id === openId, then it can be shown as open, otherwise, closed.

Comment: im not sure that i understand what u mean